# Sequence number between string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure like this

```
declare @Tmp varchar(60)
declare @Hasil varchar(60)
declare @PFID varchar(50)
declare @CntPFID int
declare @PrevPFID varchar(60)
DECLARE @CheckLetter CHAR(5)

set @PFID = 'PF-FB/ALL/009/MKX/VI/16'

set @CheckLetter = (UPPER(RIGHT((CAST(SUBSTRING(@PFID, 10, 4) AS VARCHAR(5))), 3)))

select @CntPFID = count(pfid) 
from pf 
where pfid like '%'+ right(@PFID, 9) 
  and pfid like ''+  left(@PFID, 13) +'%'

if @CntPFID = 1
begin
    set @Tmp = (UPPER(RIGHT((CAST(SUBSTRING(@PFID, 10, 4) AS VARCHAR(5))), 3))) + '-' + '01'
    set @Hasil = replace(@PFID, replace(@CheckLetter, ' ', ''), @Tmp)
end
else 
begin
    set @Tmp = (UPPER(RIGHT((CAST(SUBSTRING(@PFID, 10, 4) AS VARCHAR(5))), 3))) + '-0' + cast(@CntPFID as varchar(3))
    set @Hasil = replace(@PFID, replace(@CheckLetter, ' ', ''), @Tmp)
end

select @Hasil
```

I was stuck when the record data already reach 'PF-FB/ALL/009-09/MKX/VI/16' the next number becoming PF-FB/ALL/009-**010**/MKX/VI/16 (there is three digits = 010) while I want it will be PF-FB/ALL/009-**10**/MKX/VI/16 (2 digits running).

Is there any dynamically way without using condition else if > 9 ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you need to change: `'-0' + cast(@CntPFID as varchar(3))`, try this way:

```
declare  @CntPFID int;
set @CntPFID = 9;
select '-' + right('00'+ cast(@CntPFID as varchar(3)),2)
set @CntPFID = 11;
select '-' + right('00'+ cast(@CntPFID as varchar(3)),2)
```